# Why isn't background-image working on a td?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want a background for a `td`.  Here is my code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"> 
  <tr colspan="2">
<td> 
  <img src="Images/1.png" width="567" height="108" />           
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr colspan="2" >
<td style="background-image:url(Images/2.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;"> 



            </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that no images are displayed in the second row.

If I use:

```
<img src="Images/2.png" width="567" height="108" />
```

then the image 2.png  does display.

Why isn't my first image appearing?

Comment: @emaadali , yes and to make sure I tried <img src="Images/2.png" width="567" height="108" /> and could see the image

Comment: You code has some [obvious errors](http://validator.w3.org/) and smells like you are [abusing tables for layout](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)

Comment: try it in div with giving it static height and width.

Comment: you should define a new css class for this td.. avoid inline styling :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cell has no content, so it has no height, and there are no other cells in the row to give it a height, so there is no space to display a background image in.

Comment: yes it worked very well, but if I have a pragraph <p></p> how to do text wrap in it , because when I put a bulk of words in it it be out of the cell, is there auto wrap

Answer (score 2):

Try putting some content inside the the `td`.  Ex:

```
<td style="background-image:url(Images/2.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;"> 
  <p>Hi, I am some content.</p>
</td>
```

If that resolves, then you'll know that the problem is that no background appears when an element has no dimensions.

Comment: yes it worked very well, but if I have a pragraph <p></p> how to do text wrap in it , because when I put a bulk of words in it it be out of the cell, is there auto wrap

Comment: @AMH - I don't understand your question.  PS - If you have a new question, you should probably search for existing questions, and maybe post a new one.